# Can I get DuckDuckGo to show less US-and-allies news sources?

Tags: search, duckduckgo

I'm using the DuckDuckGo search engine in English. Now, I realize there will be more prominent and popular news sources in English in places like the US, the UK, Canada and Australia; but - since these world states are mostly allied politically, the effect is that I get perspectives which are relatively close to each other.

Is it possible to somehow coax DDG into showing me more sources from other world states, earlier in the list list of results?